# I want to extract a particular part or values from the string using regex

Tags: java

My String is something like in this pattern:

```
{ "x_y_z":{data}, "a_b_c_d":{[my data]}, "q_w_e":{data} }
```

Data I want to extract is:

```
{[my data]}
```

Could point me into a direction how to achieve this?

Comment: what have you already tried?

Comment: Is your string a JSON object? If it's a JSON object, you should parse it, do not use regex.

Comment: To add to the JSON related comment above, some of the libraries that can be explored are Json-simple or Gson.

Comment: `jsonObject.get("a_b_c_d")`

Answer (score 0):

Using a JSON parser is a more robust and readable way to go, but to answer the question:

```
String abcd = str.replaceAll(".*\"a_b_c_d\"\\s*:\\s*(.*?)\\s*,.*", "$1");
```

The regex matches the entire input and captures the target as group 1, and the replacement is the captured group.

Comment: Will this work if there are spaces in the capture group's data?

Comment: @cricket_007 yes. It captures everything up to, but not including, the next comma (discarding any spaces that may be just before the comma).